# SCSS child class in html

Tags: html, class, sass, selector

Hey guys assume I have a scss file like this

```
.wallet-gdi-info-container {
    border: 1px solid $theme-main-color;
    display: flex;
    min-width: 150px;
    max-height: 100px;
    font-family: HelveticaRegular, sans-serif;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 20px;

    .title {
        font-size: 12px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: black;
    }

    .currency {
        font-size: 18px;
        margin-right: 15px;
        margin-left: 15px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: black;
    }

    .currency-bitcoin {
        font-size: 14px;
        align-self: flex-end;
        justify-self: flex-end;
        margin-right: 19px;
        color: gray;
    }
}
```

Now how can I give a class of .wallet-gdi-info-container's title (exactly) to html?
For example

```
<div class="wallet-gdi-info-container">
    <div class="wallet-gdi-info-container title">Total Invested</div>
    <div class="wallet-gdi-info-container currency">12000 EUR</div>
    <div class="wallet-gdi-info-container currency-bitcoin">~2.23 BTC</div>
</div>
```

Does not work fine because there is already .title class defined in the scss. I need to give .title class which is child of .wallet-gdi-info-container exactly. How can I achieve this?

Comment: If I understood correctly, just leave `.title`, `.currency` and `.currency-bitcoin` classes on `.wallet-dgi-info-container`'s children.

Comment: yes, i shared the code, you can see.

Comment: wait how shall i write them in html? I mean how correctly write.

Comment: Just let the parent have `wallet-dgi-info-container` class. Remove it from the others.

Comment: Did not work. It seems the parent of .wallet-gdi-info-container also has .title in it. So it inherits that .title properties in first place.

Comment: If I copy .wallet-gdi-info-container's class to it's parent child, I mean don't write in separately as root will that work?

Comment: Why don't you change the title class for something like inner-title or title-2?

Comment: I could do that, but simple solutions is not always the best. By the way I did it, I just needed to move .wallet-gdi-info-container class to it's parent class(as child) so title now goes as .wallet-gdi-info-container's title exactly, thanks for helping.

Comment: Or you could just chain classes and reference it as `.wallet-dgi-info-container.title`.